# Efectos click jQuery en asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Soy principante en `jQuery` y `javascript` pero lo que quiero es que cuando presionen clic en el botón todo ese footer de color azul crezca hacia arriba y se quede ahí.

Este es mi código `jQuery`:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".footer").animate({height:"900px"},300);
    });
});
</script>
```

Este es el cuerpo de mi página :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <article class="container ">
    <div class="cuerpo row ">
       <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
           <div class="text-center">

            <img src="../img/Qapaq.png" style="width:70px;"/>

            <h4 class="titulo">Financiera QapaQ</h4>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </article>
        <div class="footer container">
            <div class="row">
               <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
                    <div class="text-center">
            <footer>
                <button>Iniciar Session</button>
                <h3 class="footer-letra">Iniciar Sessión</h3>
            </footer>
                        <//div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Esta es la imagen de mi página para que me puedan entender:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisé en la console y me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("button").click(function () {
            $(".footer").animate({height:"900px"},300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <article class="container ">
    <div class="cuerpo row ">
       <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
           <div class="text-center">

            <img src="../img/Qapaq.png" style="width:70px;"/>

            <h4 class="titulo">Financiera QapaQ</h4>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </article>
        <div class="footer container">
            <div class="row">
               <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
                    <div class="text-center">
            <footer>
                <button>Iniciar Session</button>
                <h3 class="footer-letra">Iniciar Sessión</h3>
            </footer>
                        <//div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Error:**

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ browserLink:37
ajax @ browserLink:37
ajaxAbort @ browserLink:62
abort @ browserLink:62
stop @ browserLink:62
(anonymous) @ browserLink:62
dispatch @ browserLink:37
h @ browserLink:37
```

Comment: @dev hola mi hermano entonces lo que puse primero no es javascript , disculpa soy nuevo en esto y no se diferenciar que es javascript y jquery

Comment: no estuve del todo claro. la porción de código donde añade el  `$("button").click..` está después de la llamada a Jquery es decir después de `<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`, sí está después estaría correcto , si está antes no y podría ser esa la razón de un posible error.

Comment: Dev muchas gracias ya entendí , si esque lo que trataba de realizar es cuando presionen clicl ese color azul cresca  y bueno eso intentaba hacer en jquery soy nuevo En jquery  , gracias hermano

Comment: ¿Resolvió su problema con mi  comentario? . si es así y ya no empleará esta pregunta podría eliminarla directamente.  Y si no se resolvió esperar una respuesta pero a primera vista lo que comente arriba puede ser su error.

Comment: En principio, debería dar igual que este antes o despues de la declaración del jquery pues en el momento que se vaya a hacer el click, estará, o debería estar, todo cargaro. (lee que te sale por consola del error, suele ser muy descriptivo) y si no lo solucionas copialo para que lo podamos ver. Te recomendaría meter los <script> en el head, por temas de rendimiento y carga de la página. También te recomendaría que le pongas un id al button y uses el id en lugar de button, es muy genérico y te podría dar problemas con otros buttons.

Comment: @Dev.Joel lo puse como me indicaste pero igual no ocurre nada ahora adjuntare el error en console.

Answer (score 0):

Si eres nuevo lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar un plugin antes que programar.

Te adjunto un link de uno que funciona muy fluído:

Demo: http://stolksdorf.github.io/Parallaxjs/

Git:  https://github.com/stolksdorf/Parallaxjs